# EF silently ignores unsupported(?) types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use code-first apporach and I have a simple table which I'm trying to save in an SQL Compact(SqlServerCe.4.0) database. Among others I have a property of type `uint`. When the table gets created in the DB I can see all but my `uint` column. Changing `uint` to `int` or `long` makes the column to appear. Changing it back to `uint` and it's no longer there(of course I re-create the DB every time).
So I have 2 questions:

1. Why is `uint` unsupported?(not very interested in but good to know)
2. Why EF *quietly* ignored the property without notifying me that I can't use a property of the `uint` type?(this is the main question I need an answer to)

Comment: The supported types are provider dependent, and they should be documented in the provider itself... in the case of SQLClient, they are described in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896344(v=vs.100).aspx . I know this doesn't fully answer your question about why it does support some and why it doesn't support others, and why it doesn't notify you about unsupported types, but I guess those are just design decisions and there's no real good answer

Comment: @Jcl, so there is no way to change the behavior to notify a user when it encounters a non-supported column type?

Comment: not that I know of (I'd have written an answer if I knew!)